# Mediawiki 1.37.2 Visualeditor: Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: (curl error: 77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Tags: ssl, mediawiki, parsoid, mediawiki-visualeditor

Fresh install of Mediawiki 1.37.2 on Ubuntu gives an error with the visual editor:

Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: (curl error: 77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

in LocalSettings.php is only put:
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );

How could this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Can well be a permission issue. Make sure that your certificate is readable by both root and web server user (probably, www-data). Can be done by `chown root:www-data fullchain.pem privkey.pem; chmod g+r fullchain.pem privkey.pem`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found out though now what it was.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the problem:

This page helped out: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/3793

It is caused by a wrong certificate being used on curl. To fix the problem the following was executed:

- Download the cacert.pem file from the Curl's site: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html;
- Place certificate inside the domain's root directory.
- Specify the path to it in php.ini.
  curl.cainfo = /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/cacert.pem